# How can i change label text from different button in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, label

I descripted my problem in script comments. Function GraphicClassStructure is only for create buttons and label. But mainly function is plusButton_click. I need that if i clicked on first plus button so i need change text for first added label.

**Script: (Problem is here: plusButton_click, i descripted problem to case)**

```
class GraphicClassStructure : GraphicPosition
{
    // Button
    public Button plus;
    public PictureBox classBackround = new PictureBox();
    // Label
    Label points;

    public void CreateSpellsButton()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                plus = new Button();
                points = new Label();

                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0:
                        points.Location = Location[1][i];
                        points.Location = new Point(points.Location.X + 8, points.Location.Y + 45);
                        plus.Location = Location[2][i];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        plus.Location = Location[2][i];
                        plus.Location = new Point(plus.Location.X + 205, plus.Location.Y);
                        points.Location = Location[1][i];
                        points.Location = new Point(points.Location.X + 213, points.Location.Y + 45);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        plus.Location = Location[2][i];
                        plus.Location = new Point(plus.Location.X + 410, plus.Location.Y);
                        points.Location = Location[1][i];
                        points.Location = new Point(points.Location.X + 418, points.Location.Y + 45);
                        break;
                }

                // Labels for point

                points.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                points.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(193)))), ((int)(((byte)(196)))), ((int)(((byte)(181)))));
                points.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                points.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                points.Name = "points";
                points.Name = spells.Name + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
                if (i >= 6)
                    points.Text = "0 / 2";
                else
                    points.Text = "0 / 1";
                points.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(classUniqueButtons_VisibleChanged);

                // Plus
                plus.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                plus.BackgroundImage = BuildResource.plus;
                plus.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                plus.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                plus.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
                plus.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
                plus.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                plus.Name = "plus";
                plus.Size = Size[0][9];
                plus.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
                plus.Name = plus.Name + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
                plus.Click += new EventHandler(plusButton_click);
                plus.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(classUniqueButtons_VisibleChanged);
                plus.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(this.classButton_MouseEnter);
                plus.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(this.classButton_MouseLeave);

                classBackround.Controls.Add(plus);
                classBackround.Controls.Add(points);
            }
        }
    }

    private void plusButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentButton = sender as Button;
        var name = currentButton.Name;

        switch (name)
        {
            // Ultimate
            case "plus0_0":
                // If i clicked on this button so i need change text for first added label
                // I try this, but it changed only last added labe
                points.Text = "test";
                break;
            case "plus0_1":
                // If i clicked on this button so i need change text for second added label
                break;
        }
    }

    private void minusButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentButton = sender as Button;
        var name = currentButton.Name;

        switch (name)
        {
            // Ultimate
            case "minus0_0":
                // If i clicked on this button so i need change text for first added label
                // I try this, but it changed only last added labe
                points.Text = "test";
                break;
            case "minus0_1":
                // If i clicked on this button so i need change text for second added label
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is spells ? what does it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple to do here what you need

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                plus = new Button();
                //tag is an object and can be used to reference any  other object 
                plus.Tag = new Label();
```

and to retrieve what you need do this

```
 private void plusButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentButton = sender as Button;
        var name = currentButton.Name;

        switch (name)
        {
            // Ultimate
            case "plus0_0":

                (currentButton.Tag as Label).Text = "test";
                break;
            case "plus0_1":
                (currentButton.Tag as Label).Text ="test2"
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global reference to the label which you have overwritten in each iteration of your loop. Therefore it always references the last label. Since you always add the label after the button and have the reference to the button you can probably get the correct label like this:

```
Label pointsLabel = (Label)classBackround.Controls[classBackround.Controls.IndexOf(currentButton) + 1]
```